# how to implement the runtime compression of texture?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, agal

I've read the doc here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d5b.html

> Flash Player 11.4 and AIR 3.4 support runtime texture compression,
>   which is useful in certain situations, such as when rendering dynami
>   textures from vector art. To use runtime texture compression, perform
>   the following steps:
>
> Create the texture object by calling the Context3D.createTexture()
>   method, passing either
>   flash.display3D.Context3DTextureFormat.COMPRESSED
>   orflash.display3D.Context3DTextureFormat.COMPRESSED_ALPHA in the third
>   parameter. Using the flash.display3D.textures.Texture instance
>   returned by createTexture(), call either
>   flash.display3D.textures.Texture.uploadFromBitmapData()
>   orflash.display3D.textures.Texture.uploadFromByteArray(). These
>   methods upload and compress the texture in one step.

I tried to follow the steps but get an error:

> Error: Error #3763: Sampler 0 binds a texture that that does not match
>   the read mode specified in AGAL. Reading compressed or single/dual
>   channel textures must be explicitly declared.
>             at flash.display3D::Context3D/drawTriangles()

should I put some instructions on agal side also?

here is the full code:

NOTE: I didn't use the embedded png for texture after I tried it and failed, just a empty bitmapdata created runtime not gonna work on my macos flash player 11.8

grabbed the AGALMiniAssembler.as from here :
https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/com/adobe/utils/AGALMiniAssembler.as

```
package sandbox
{
    import com.adobe.utils.AGALMiniAssembler;
    import com.adobe.utils.PerspectiveMatrix3D;

    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage3D;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display3D.Context3D;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DProfile;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DProgramType;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DRenderMode;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DTextureFormat;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DVertexBufferFormat;
    import flash.display3D.IndexBuffer3D;
    import flash.display3D.Program3D;
    import flash.display3D.VertexBuffer3D;
    import flash.display3D.textures.Texture;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Matrix3D;

    import core.Scene3D;

    [SWF(width="600",height="800",frameRate="60")]
    public class TestCompressedTexture extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="../../assets/tex_cube.png")]
        private var TexCube:Class;
        private var _swfHeight:int;
        private var _swfWidth:int;
        public var context3D:Context3D;
        public var viewMatrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
        public var projectionMatrix:PerspectiveMatrix3D = new PerspectiveMatrix3D();

        public var meshIndexData:Vector.<uint> = Vector.<uint>
            ([
                0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,   
            ]);

        public var meshVertexData:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([
            //x,y,z     u,v    nx,ny,nz
            -1, -1,  1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1,
            1, -1,  1, 1, 0,  0, 0, 1,
            1,  1,  1, 1, 1,  0, 0, 1,
            -1,  1,  1, 0, 1,  0, 0, 1,
        ]);
        private var indexBuffer:IndexBuffer3D;
        private var vertexBuffer:VertexBuffer3D;
        private var program:Program3D;
        private var _modelViewProjection:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
        private var modelMatrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
        private var texture:Texture;
        private var uvBuffer:VertexBuffer3D;

        public function TestCompressedTexture()
        {
            _swfHeight = 600;
            _swfWidth = 800;
            if (stage!=null){
                init();
            }else{
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
            }
            projectionMatrix.identity();
            projectionMatrix.perspectiveFieldOfViewRH(45.0,_swfWidth/_swfHeight,0.001,100.0);
            modelMatrix.identity();
            viewMatrix.identity();
            viewMatrix.prependTranslation(0,0,-5);
            super();
        }

        private function init(e:Event=null):void{
            if (hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE))
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE,onContext3DCreate);
            stage.stage3Ds[0].requestContext3D(Context3DRenderMode.AUTO,Context3DProfile.BASELINE_EXTENDED);
        }

        protected function onContext3DCreate(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);
            var t:Stage3D = e.target as Stage3D;
            context3D = t.context3D;
            if (context3D == null){
                return;
            }
            context3D.enableErrorChecking = true;

            context3D.configureBackBuffer(_swfWidth,_swfHeight,0,true);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Scene3D.SCENE3D_CREATED));

            createProgram();
            createTexture();
            createBuffer();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);
        }

        public function createProgram():void{
            var vsa:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();

            var vs:String = 
                "m44 op, va0, vc0\n" +
                "mov v0, va1\n" //uv
                ;
            var fs:String =
                "tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,repeat,nomip>\n"+
                "mov oc ft0 \n"
                ;
            program = vsa.assemble2(context3D,1,vs,fs);
            context3D.setProgram(program);
        }

        public function createBuffer():void{
            indexBuffer = context3D.createIndexBuffer(meshIndexData.length);
            indexBuffer.uploadFromVector(meshIndexData,0,meshIndexData.length);


            vertexBuffer = context3D.createVertexBuffer(meshVertexData.length/8,8);
            vertexBuffer.uploadFromVector(meshVertexData,0,meshVertexData.length /8);


        }

        public function createTexture():void{
//          texture = context3D.createTexture(512, 512, Context3DTextureFormat.BGRA, false);
            texture = context3D.createTexture(512, 512, Context3DTextureFormat.COMPRESSED, false);
//          var texCube:BitmapData = new TexCube().bitmapData;
//          trace(texCube.height,texCube.width);
            var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(512,512);

            texture.uploadFromBitmapData(bmd);
        }

        protected function enterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            context3D.clear();

            _modelViewProjection.identity();
            _modelViewProjection.append(modelMatrix);
            _modelViewProjection.append(viewMatrix);
            _modelViewProjection.append(projectionMatrix);
            // pass our matrix data to the shader program
            context3D.setProgramConstantsFromMatrix(
                Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,
                0, _modelViewProjection, true );

            context3D.setVertexBufferAt(0, vertexBuffer, 0, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3);
            context3D.setVertexBufferAt(1, vertexBuffer, 3, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_2);
            context3D.setTextureAt(0,texture);

            context3D.drawTriangles(indexBuffer);

            context3D.present();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While months too late for davyzhang, but for others who may land here:  the maker of Starling, who has Adobe connections experimentally implemented the code, then learned from Adobe that the recently added run-time compression function is only available for desktop systems.

https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/issues/153

Comment: Thanks, though it means my project can not use it:D, still glad to know the actual reason, Better late than never:)